# Property about algebraic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Recently I am reading about transcendental number theory, there is a statement that all algebraic integers are norm at least 1 except 0, I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Write down the definition of algebraic integer and of Norm of an algeraic integer

Comment: Well, the norm is an integer. That's a good start.

Comment: @Kuroniko Please make up you mind about what your question really is. Is the norm in your question the usual field norm or is it, as it was in one of your edits, the absolute value?

Comment: @Magdiragdag Actually I am not so clear about what the norm means now because in the statement it doesn't give me the definition of norm, I used to consider the norm just the absolute value, but it seems not true now, I am confused.

Comment: @Kuroniko If it doesn't give the definition, then it is very likely the field norm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm).

Answer (score 3):

The norm of an algebraic integer is the last coefficient of the minimal polynomial. So it is integer. If it is zero then the number is zero because minimal polynomial is irreducible

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite clear why the norm of an algebraic integer is the last coefficient of the minimal polynomial, could you please explain it for me more clearly?or give me some example?Thank you very much!

Comment: What definition of the norm are you using? This is one of the basic properties. For exapmple, if $\mathbb{F} \subset \mathbb{K}$ then  $\mathbb{K}$ can be regarded as $\mathbb{F}$-vector space. Then the minimal polynomial of $a \in \mathbb{K}$ as an operator on $\mathbb{K}$ (given by multiplication) is the minimal polynomial of $a$ as an algebraic integer. The last coefficient of the minimal polynomial is the determinant of $a$ as an operator, and that is one of the definitions of the norm.

Comment: oh sorry, maybe I don't explain the question clearly, my norm is the absolute value of the algebraic integer.

Comment: @Kuroniko If that's what you mean by norm, that's untrue. $\frac {\sqrt{5}-1}2$ has minimal polynomial $x^2+x-1$ but has absolute values roughly $.618...$ which is obviously less than one. The various definitions of norm of an algebraic number are more subtle than the one you've given here.

Comment: oh yes, maybe I do not understand the meaning of norm very well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true: neither the (field) norm of a non-zero algebraic integer has to be at least 1 (which is what the answer by user68061 uses as definition; and what is normally understood as norm), nor does the absolute value of a non-zero algebraic integer have to be at least 1 (which is what the OP seems to use).

For the first one: the norm of $\sqrt{2}$ is $\sqrt{2} \cdot - \sqrt{2} = -2$ (or, if you prefer, its minimum polynomial is $x^2-2$, so its norm is $-2$).

For the second one: the absolute value of $\sqrt{2} - 1$ is about $0.41$.

Now you could look at the absolute value of the (field) norm of a non-zero algebraic integer. That is indeed at least $1$, but that's just because it's an integer (and it can't be $0$, since $0$ is the only element with norm $0$).

Answer (score -2):

In number theory, an algebraic integer, is a complex number that is the root of some monic polynomial (leading coefficient is 1) with integer coefficients. From [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: No, but there was some confusion on the definition. Do you think it should be a comment? Is maybe better? By the way, the previous answer also does not answer the question...

Comment: Should I delete my answer? What is the good way of doing that? Can someone enlighten me? Thanks.